# JavaScript catch event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem.  I have too many events in my DOM. The upper layer is catching the deeper event.

Easy Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("p").click(function(){
                $(this).hide();
            })
            $("#second").click(function(){
                alert("second.");
            });
            $("#first").click(function(){
                alert("first.");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #first{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #second{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="first">
        <div id="second">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If someone clicks on the second div, which is enclosed by the first div, both of the divs catch the event. In this situation, how can I catch just the second div's click event, and leave the first div.

I learnt about the event bubbling, and tunnelling in C# is that the problem.  How is this problem called?
How can I solve the problem using JavaScript and jQuery. Is the solution the same?

Comment: `tunneling in C#` ?? How is that related? Have you looked at event.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: because in C# u can catch the bubbling, or the c# tunneling event. Just I have not known How does it work in js

Comment: Ahh ok. your wording threw me off. The answer below works well for you.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to stop the event from propagating up to the parent elements:

```
$("#second").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert("second.");
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EXbdt/3/**

Comment: @ryadavilli: Thanks. Looks like Chrome's having some trouble with JSFiddle.

Comment: What is about if I want that the parent the first panel does not catch the event, but the parent of parent catch that again. So the event is bornt from the second div, bubble to the first, where I set the stopPropagation, but than there is a parent where I also would like to catch the event? Is this complicated?

Comment: @user1693057: That sounds way too complicated. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I do not have to, I just would like to know, if u know this. Maybe I have to use that in the future.